# How to animate annotation/marker position in mapbox latest version(5.5.0 and above) from iOS

Tags: ios, animation, annotations, mapbox, marker

I've created a marker on the map with code below. I'm going to move the marker from point A(current) to point B using animation.

```
let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
point.coordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate // pointA
mapView.addAnnotation(point)
```

It's actually something like the link below, with the difference for iOS
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/animate-marker-position

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: I haven't come to a complete thing yet @ Luca Mastrostefano